# need help on scrolling ul element on mouseover

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to make my UL element scrollleft on mouse over but I cannot make it to work. here my fiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/MisterStorm/4ja9apqz/3/
and here my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#next').hover( function () {
    scrollCallback = setInterval(function () {
      $('#divContainer ul').animate({
        'scrollLeft': $('#divContainer ul').offset().left
      }, 500);
      console.log($('#divContainer ul').offset().left);
    }, 50);
  }, function () {
    clearInterval(scrollCallback);
  });
});
```

```css
#divContainer {
  width:300px;
  overflow:hidden;
  border:solid 1px #000;
  position: relative;
  height:20px;
}
#divContainer ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  position:absolute;
  top:0px;
  left:0px;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
#divContainer ul li {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  line-height: 20px;
  font-size: 13px;
  display: inline;
  margin-left: 3px;
  margin-right: 3px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="divContainer">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">1</a></li> 
    <li><a href="#">2</a></li> 
    <li><a href="#">3</a></li> 
    <li><a href="#">4</a></li> 
    <li><a href="#">5</a></li> 
    <li><a href="#">6</a></li> 
    <li><a href="#">7</a></li> 
    <li><a href="#">8</a></li> 
    <li><a href="#">9</a></li> 
    <li><a href="#">10</a></li> 
    <li><a href="#">11</a></li> 
    <li><a href="#">12</a></li> 
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="next">next</div>
```

any help appreciated thank's!

Comment: You're Fiddle isn't calling jQuery as a resource.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you want ??

http://jsfiddle.net/4ja9apqz/9/

I use a différent mehod because i don't understand yours.

I just take the left offest like this :

```
left_offset = $('#divContainer ul').css('left');
```

And apply left_offset -5px each 50ms and reset to 0 when the hover stop.

Answer (score 0):

Use css `:hover`

```css
#divContainer {
    width:300px;
    overflow:hidden;
    border:solid 1px #000;
    position: relative;
    height:20px
}
#divContainer ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    -webkit-transition: transform 6s ease;
    -moz-transition: transform 6s ease;
    transition: transform 6s ease
}
#divContainer ul li {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    line-height: 20px;
    font-size: 13px;
    display: inline;
    margin-left: 3px;
    margin-right: 3px;
    float: left
}
#divContainer ul:hover{
   -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
   -moz-transform: translateX(-100%);
   transform: translateX(-100%)
}
```

```html
<div id="divContainer">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">1</a></li> 
        <li><a href="#">2</a></li> 
        <li><a href="#">3</a></li> 
        <li><a href="#">4</a></li> 
        <li><a href="#">5</a></li> 
        <li><a href="#">6</a></li> 
        <li><a href="#">7</a></li> 
        <li><a href="#">8</a></li> 
        <li><a href="#">9</a></li> 
        <li><a href="#">10</a></li> 
        <li><a href="#">11</a></li> 
        <li><a href="#">12</a></li> 
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="next">next</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually i found my answer i had to put both ul and li element position absolute so that they could move.

here my updated js code (taken from my project)

```
thisObj.find('#sliderleft').hover(function () {
    scrollCalbackRight = setInterval(function () {
    var pos = optionList.holderPagerList.css('left').replace('px', '') * 1;
    if (pos < 0){
        optionList.holderPagerList.css('left', (pos * 1) + optionList.scrollerDistance);
    }
}, 50);
}, function () {
    clearInterval(scrollCalbackRight);
});
```

this also take care if the position is at the start.